# Dynamics CRM Portal Global Search

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

We are using the portal Add-On for Dynamics CRM. We've enabled "search" for our custom entity. 
When a list of custom entity records is displayed, a search box is also displayed and the search works.

But apparently the global search does not search within our custom entity. Is there a setting to qualify an entitylist for global search?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can’t add your custom entity or any entity other than listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/search#entities-searchable-in-portal-global-search).

> •   Knowledge Article
>       ◦   Notes and attachment of a knowledge article are searchable as well
>       ◦   Articles are searchable only if they are published and their Internal Only field is set to false
>       •   Blog
>       •   Blog Post
>       •   Blog Post Comment
>       •   Forum
>       •   Forum Post
>       •   Forum Thread
>       •   Idea
>       •   Idea Comment
>       •   Idea Forum
>       •   Web File
>       ◦   Attachment content of web files is searchable as well
>       •   Web Page
>       •   Incident
>
> `Apart from the entities listed here, no other entity can be enabled for global search in a portal`.